# search array of field values for one of them in drupal-6

Tags: php, arrays, drupal-6, field, nodereference

So, I have got a node reference field, which can have multiple values and I'm attempting to compose a php code, which will check all values of that field for a certain value i want and print a text if it finds it. 
I want to do it in views php field
and this is the code i have came up with so far:

```
<?php
$node = node_load($data->nid);
print $data->nid . '<br>';
if(in_array('Yog [nid:1315]', $node->field_ref_oznajomenieni)) {
print 'yoog';
}
else {
print 'niemanic';
}
?>
```

I'm somewhat bad in PHP, but:
The `node_load()` works fine and `$data->nid` returs node id for every row of my view.
This is confirmed by `print $data->nid . '|';`

Now, the if function is supposed to do what i want, search the array of values for something in the node reference field and print something too. 
I'm not sure if i should search for the nid of the referenced node, its title or how i put it in the code, whatever i try, i get the `print 'niemanic';` of the `else{}`

How should i do it exactly, please?

Comment: an alternative way to `in_array()` seams:
`foreach ($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni as $value) {
print $value . ' ya';
}`
But it doesn't print all the field values like I'd expect it to.
It does however print exactly as many "ya" as there are values in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clear:
The code is to search for a value in a node reference field and print something only if it is found.

one way:

```
// less RAM usage
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$napis = '';
foreach ($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni as $value) {
if ($value[nid] == '1315') {
$napis = 'Yog';
}
// if (!($napis)) $napis = 'niemanic'; // for testing purpose
}
print $napis;
```

another way: (untested, may lack some brackets)

```
// flattened matrix way
$plaskatablica = array();
foreach ($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni as $value) {
$plaskatablica[] = $value[nid];

if(in_array('1315', $plaskatablica)) {
print 'Yog';
}
}
```

Here is what i have figured by myself:

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$ii = 0;
foreach ($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni as $value) {
if(in_array('1315', array_values($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni[$ii]))) {
print 'Yog';
}
++$ii;
}
```

This is `print_r($node->field_ref_oznajomenieni);` output of an example field:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [nid] => 1320 ) 
[1] => Array ( [nid] => 1315 ) 
[2] => Array ( [nid] => 1518 ) 
[3] => Array ( [nid] => 1519 ) 
[4] => Array ( [nid] => 1525 ) 
)
```